# consulta sql phpmyadmin

Tags: sql

tengo la siguiente tabla..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y realice esta consulta:

```
`select a.*
from a

inner join b on b.id_a = a.id

where a.id not in (
    select b.id_a 
    from b 
    where b.estado > 0 and b.estado < 23)
`
```

la consulta deberia arrojarme solo los datos de los registros 123455 y 123454. Pero me arroja datos tambien del registro 123456. En phpmyadmin lo probe. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Podrias mostrar que tratas de obtener? y supongo que tu consulta es en mysql (phpmyadmin es solo una ide para conectarse a una base de datos)...

Comment: no debo obtener los ids de A que en B  tengan un estado menor a 21

Comment: @gbianchi [Aquí se hizo un enorme esfuerzo por ayudar a OP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/491621/29967) (ver comentarios), cosa que por cierto OP no ha  tomado en cuenta, abriendo una nueva pregunta con el mismo problema. Cree incluso [un EMV](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ps4viJARq9HjfmPMDo4UY/0) instando a OP a que lo pruebe y nos explique por qué la consulta debe arrojar los registros que él dice.

Comment: buenisimo @A.Cedano.. cerramos esta... y va la advertencia

Comment: No dupliques tus preguntas. Duplicas el esfuerzo por entender tu problema, y no permitis que otras personas te ayuden.